# Djnago with Paypal for server site integration

Tags: django, paypal, django-paypal

I am using django 3 and django-paypal module, It's my first time with payment integration so
Is there any better way to just add paypal like client site integration in production?? i am trying many tutorial docs but they are not sufficient !
it would be highly appreciated if anyone suggest me any best way and also with the links to follow .

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Create two routes that return JSON, one for 'Create an Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). You can use the Checkout-Python-SDK.

Pair your two routes with the JS front-end: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Thank you sir ! but i just want to pay a fixed amount without that name address and all these thing , just like the client site integration in pay pal, something like that....but thanks for response

Comment: Doesn't change anything